# How to translate comments in code blocks using Sphinx

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx

I write documentation for a project using `Sphinx`. I have code examples (defined as `code-block`s, both literally included and just typed inline). In these code examples there are comments, but when I produce documentation translation, they are not extracted into `.po` files, and obviously are not translated.

How can I translate comments in code examples?

I found other questions about Sphinx modifications. The answers proposed modifying `conf.py` (making some hooks), creating `role`s or `extensions`. I never did that before and I don't know where to start and what solution would be better. Is there any existing solution for this problem?

UPD. These are examples of code I want to show in my documentation:

```
git clone https://github.com/ynikitenko/lena
# most of requirements are for development only
pip install -r lena/requirements.txt
```

(here I'd like to translate the comment). A more difficult (maybe not so needed) example is this:

```
class End(object):
    """Stop sequence here."""

    def run(self, flow):
        """Exhaust all preceding flow and stop iteration
        (yield nothing to the following flow).
        """
        for val in flow:
            pass
        return
        # otherwise it won't be a generator
        yield "unreachable"
```

These examples are formatted with the directive

```
.. code-block::
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an example? Like what the comments look like, and what kind of code examples you'd like to see.

Comment: @zkytony sure. For example, here is an inline comment https://lena.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#from-pypi I'd like to translate "# if you plan to render LaTeX templates". A larger code example may be here, with full documentation strings (but this situation may be less important): https://lena.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/answers.html#ex-1 .

Comment: @zkytony I added that to the question, thanks for your asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to the official [sphinx-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sphinx-users) google group, and this is [the answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/l9LIu_x3Jyg) from Matt from Documatt:

> It's impossible. Sphinx will have to understand comments in every language.
>
> If you want to translate comments in code-block (and literal blocks after ::), you must translate them all. Add [gettext_additional_targets](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-gettext_additional_targets) = ["literal-block"] to your `conf.py` and re-run POT/PO update.

The code lines remain in the "translations" of code, but now the problem is solved for me.

Comment: Maybe I should add that I got rid of comments shown in my original question. They should be avoided, and most of code doesn't have to be translated. But sometimes it's useful.